# Facebook android sdk send request

Tags: android, facebook

Is there any way that we can send a request invitation to user/friend from facebook android sdk?

Thank you very much.

Best Regards,
Eve

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#graph)

Comment: Please provide [more substantive details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72002/141525) rather than just posting a link.